# Supporting two languages in travis.ci file

Tags: travis-ci

I'm building a python package which is mostly c++ code (think numpy)

My travis file is currently

```
language: cpp
compiler:
  - gcc
  - clang
os:
  - linux
  - osx
dist: trusty

script: "make pcst_fast_test && ./pcst_fast_test"

notifications: 
...
```

But I've also written some python tests in a file called `test_pcst_fast.py`. Is there some way to call those from travis as well?

It seems ambiguous as to [whether travis supports multiple languages in one file](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4090), but it seems like most people pull this off despite only listing one language under the `language` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Travis doesn't support multiple languages per job yet.

Look at categories `after_success` and `after_script`  [in the Travis build lifecycle docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#The-Build-Lifecycle)

Also, you can add more build scripts, they will run independently, just list them like this:

```
script:
    - "make pcst_fast_test && ./pcst_fast_test"
    - "./test_pcst_fast.py"
```

If there is no python installed (not sure about `c` builds), you can install it, check out this [.travis.yml](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/659383bfc430688db692a4c3bbc3452b84696f11/.travis.yml), it installs custom python interpreter as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add multiple languages, which explains the behavior you are seeing, and the node_js setting will only be recognized in a node language project.

What you can do is utilize the incorporated nvm in TravisCI.

For example, you can include

- nvm install 0.10
- nvm use 0.10

in your before_install section to download the latest v0.10.x release of node.

However,

On a Travis Java build environment, you can use nvm to manage Node.js runtimes:

.travis.yml

```
language: java

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

env:
  - NODE_VERSION="0.12"

before_install:
  - nvm install $NODE_VERSION
```

If your Node version is very recent, you might have to update nvm too.

To update nvm, write this in your .travis.yml:

```
before_install:
  - wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/nvm.sh -O ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
  - source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
  - nvm install 5 # for Node v5
  - node --version
```

The above example shows how to first update to nvm v0.31, to then obtain Node v5.